# Histogram in Matlab for data bigger than a threshold

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

How can I plot a histogram of a vector (say B) for elements of the vector which are bigger than a number (say N)?

Comment: `B(B>N)` will give you those elements

Comment: Sardar has given you the key bit of information, but you need to show us what you've tried...

Answer (score 0):

If you generated a column vector of 30 random numbers from a uniform distribution:

```
x = rand(30,1);
```

And wanted to use a cutoff of N = 0.3 (from your notation above), instead of using all the values:

```
hist(x(x>0.3));
```